# Testing in OSGIContext

Tags: java, junit, osgi

could you suggest any working tip, how to change order of services in OSGI test environment without modifying of tested classes and generated descriptors?

I am testing a custom class, initialized in test OSGI environment, `org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.junit.OsgiContext`, with a `List` of multiple service instances implementing the same interface. Order of service instances is specified statically with `SERVICE_RANKING` property annotation and generated xml descriptors in OSGI-INF folder.

I would like to simulate switch of the `SERVICE_RANKING` and the oder of services in local test environment in the way, how service order could be switched in the real OSGI container.

Service class example:

```
    @Component
    @Service(MyService.class)
    public class PlainService implements MyService {

      @Property(label = "Service Ranking", intValue = PlainService.DEFAULT_RANKING,
          description = "set lower value to get higher priority of service",
          propertyPrivate = false)
      static final String PROPERTY_RANKING = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING;
      static final int DEFAULT_RANKING = 999;

    ...
    }
```

Service container class example:

```
@Component
@Service(MyService.class)
public class PlainServiceContainer implements MyServiceContainer {

  @Reference(name = "myService", referenceInterface = MyService.class,
      cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
  private final RankedServices<MyService> myService = new RankedServices<>();

  ...

  void bindMyService(MyService service, Map<String, Object> props) {
    ...
  }

  void unbindMyService(MyService service, Map<String, Object> props) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I expect there could be a property definition, which have to change `SERVICE_RANKING` at the moment of service initialization:

```
OsgiContext context = new OsgiContext();
context.registerInjectActivateService(new PlainService(), ImmutableMap.of(Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, 989));
```

The actual example with ranking **989** does not work and service is still initialized with ranking **999**, but there should be working case, which changes it.